# win32 assembly programming graphics card

Tags: windows, assembly, graphics

I am currently learning assembler on Windows 7, and I want to make a game (for educational purposes only). I found a resource on how to program the VGA in assembly on DOS, using the mode 13h. That got me thinking: Is there a method of directly programming the graphics card in Windows 7 without the use of a high-level graphics library? If that is not an option, can you write graphical programs with a graphics library from assembly?

Thanks in advance,

RileyH

Comment: You can use [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/) to run DOS programs in Windows. And you can write Windows GUI programs in assembly too. GunnerInc has written a tutorial on how to write GUI programs in assembly: [NASM - Cross OS App For Linux/Windows Using GTK](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/292403-nasm-cross-os-app-for-linuxwindows-using-gtk/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a high level graphics library, limit yourself to low level stuff within one, like `SetPixel()`; that's pretty much the level of service that `int 13H` offers. And no, it's not possible to use `int 13H` or work directly with hardware in Windows. And you don't want VGA mode anyway - it's a huge step down in capabilities for every sensible modern graphics card.

You can write in assembly all you want, but it'd be rather pointless; the top of the call stack is not, typically, where the bottlenecks are. At least not for 2D games.

So learn GDI and/or DirectX. And don't use assembly unless and until you know you absolutely have to. Assembly is not for educational projects.

Comment: I completely disagree when you say that "Assembly is not for educational projects". Learning Assembly teaches a lot about how a computer works at the hardware level and experimenting with Assembly allows you to grasp the subject in a way you(general) can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows runs in protected mode, you can't access HW resources directly from user mode. All HW resources including graphics card are accessible from Kernel mode modules (i.e. drivers) only. If you need access from user mode, you need to address the driver of your card to perform the requested operations. The interface to it isn't just sending assembly commands that you want to use but a defined set of exposed functions. High-level graphics library might hide the need to know this interface and its usage. Addressing graphics library depends entirely on specific library definition and (again) exposed interfaces. Basically, it should be addressable from any language, including assembly.

Comment: Could you recommend any specific graphics library that I should use?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention mode 13h, I'll assume you want to do 2D games. You can handle the screen buffer yourself, in any format you choose (256 colour RGB, palettized, 24-bit ARGB, etc.), then "render" it via a higher level library like [libSDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), or maybe even GDI in Windows itself. Hitting the graphics card directly isn't something I'd recommend (extremely complex)

Comment: But is it actually possible? That is, can I do the same stuff I was doing with the DOS VGA on Windows 7?

Comment: Not with todays cards, no. Like icepack says above, HW resources are protected. You can hit the drivers from assembly, although I don't see any point in that. - But, I guess you could run a DOS/286 emulator to emulate the environments of yore, and do your assembly there? See [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com)